# Can somebody please translate main 4 symbols and the 6 little ones for me? (Characters identified: 格物致知)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Can somebody please translate main 4 symbols and the 6 little ones for me?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[格物致知](http://xh.5156edu.com/html4/5357.html) - refers to study the principles of things to gain knowledge

[丁酉](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/937119511376473972) - 2017 (or 1957)

秋 - autumn

杜金恆 /Dù jīn héng/ - author's name

*These are called 'Chinese characters', not 'symbols'*

Comment: "symbol" isn't wrong just not precise

Comment: Thank you for helping me- I appreciate that.